# Notification Service for Blackberry OS 4.5 application

Tags: user-interface, blackberry, integration, notifications, rim-4.5

I am developing an application similar to email application.Whenever new message is received my notification service should indicate change to user by updating icon,also, the notification service should continuosly listen to server for incoming events.

I am developing in os version 4.5.

Comment: Itsteju, see update. btw, how do you update icon of visible app from background app (service)? are you using HomeScreen.updateIcon with alternate entry point?

Comment: i am trying to establish interprocess communication between to apps.

Comment: I see. So when there are updates, notification service app will trigger main visible app to update icon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no ApplicationIndicator in RIM OS < 4.6 (see bb forum thread)

> you have several options to notify the
>   user (none of them is the indicator,
>   unfortunately). you can:
>
> - play a sound
> - trigger the vibration
> - trigger a customizable notification (so the user can decide)
> - change the application icon
> - paint a text on the application icon
> - change the application title

[how to show notification icon in v4.2 to v4.5 versions](http://rim.lithium.com/rim/board/message?board.id=java_dev&thread.id=44357)

- Play sound with with [Alert.startAudio](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Alert.html#startVibrate(int))
- Change application icon with [HomeScreen.updateIcon](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/homescreen/HomeScreen.html#updateIcon(net.rim.device.api.system.Bitmap))
- Change app name with [HomeScreen.setName](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/homescreen/HomeScreen.html#setName(java.lang.String))
- Trigger vibration with [Alert.startVibrate](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Alert.html#startVibrate(int))

And yes, to exchange data between two applications it's better to use [GlobalEventListener](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800620/What_Is_-_Global_Events_and_Global_Event_Listeners.html?nodeid=800527&vernum=0)

Comment: Thanks Coldice, actually I want to know how can I transfer data between 2 apps, one is my own app. and other is notification app.
Also,which api do I need to use for this? Notifications API or GlobalEvent Listener?

Comment: Youre welcome, see update. I'm curioouse - what is this notification app like?

Comment: Notification application , what i meant is, the application which will autorun on startup and will listen to events from server