# Add a notification icon at the status bar in BlackBerry JDE 4.5.0

Tags: user-interface, blackberry, notifications, integration, rim-4.5

I'm writing a Java application in [BlackBerry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BlackBerry) JDE 4.5 that will start listening for some event at the start up. I want to display a small icon at the status bar.

I know its support in version 4.6.0 of the BlackBerry API set with ApplicationIcon, ApplicationIndicator and ApplicationIndicatorRegistry classes but which classes are there in BlackBerry JDE 4.5.0 API set?

**Update**

I think some support is there for 4.5.0 as I'm using Blackberry Pearl 8100 with OS v4.5.0.81 which displays Notification Icons at status bar for any incoming messages or calls.

I made the Alternale Entry point & Main CLDC app like this article below,

[How To - Setup an alternate entry point for my application](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800738/800901/How_To_-_Setup_an_alternate_entry_point_for_my_application.html?nodeid=800820&vernum=0)

I have got an article as,

[How to - Make a running UI application go to the background and resume in the foreground](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800639/How_to_-_Make_a_running_UI_application_go_to_the_background_and_resume_in_the_foreground.html?nodeid=800545&vernum=0)

in which its said that

**The alternate entry is going to call the main method with the parameter that is passed in, regardless of whether the application is running.**

But in my case the main() is not getting called when I click on appIcon when the app is running in background.

It only updates appIcon & appName which is previously set in Alternate Entry Point.

So I m not getting where the control goes if its not calling main() when clicked on updatedIcon?

Is anyone has any idea on this issue?

---

I updated the appIcon & appName.

Now what I want is "When clicked on updatedIcon a particular screen should be opened & when the user goes back to Main Menu the app should get its original Icon, app name & the flow should go through main() when clicked on original app Icon"

I was thinking when I click on updated appIcon the control will go to main() but instead of calling main() it says,

```
Starting AppName
AppName already running
```

& directly it goes to first screen. and when I come back to Main Menu the app has updated icon & name

So how to get it?

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately it's not possible. What you can do is update application icon.

Also there are alternative ways of notification:
[Notification Service for Blackberry OS 4.5 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465259/notification-service-for-blackberry-os-4-5-application)

### Update Application Icon

[alt text http://img211.imageshack.us/img211/4527/icoupdate1.jpg](http://img211.imageshack.us/img211/4527/icoupdate1.jpg)[alt text http://img697.imageshack.us/img697/3981/icon.jpg](http://img697.imageshack.us/img697/3981/icon.jpg)[alt text http://img687.imageshack.us/img687/256/iconactive.jpg](http://img687.imageshack.us/img687/256/iconactive.jpg)[alt text http://img130.imageshack.us/img130/3277/icoupdate2.jpg](http://img130.imageshack.us/img130/3277/icoupdate2.jpg)[alt text http://img691.imageshack.us/img691/6459/icoupdate3.jpg](http://img691.imageshack.us/img691/6459/icoupdate3.jpg)
Background running application:

```
public class NotifIconSrvc extends Application {

 private int mCount = 0;
 private int mSize = 0;

 public NotifIconSrvc() {
  Timer timer = new Timer();
  timer.schedule(sendEventTask, 1000, 3000);
 }

 TimerTask sendEventTask = new TimerTask() {

  public void run() {
   // Post the GlobalEvent.
   // Long = ci.samples.45.notificon
   ApplicationManager.getApplicationManager().postGlobalEvent(
     0x5a9f7caa171ab7b8L, mCount++, mSize++);
  }
 };

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  NotifIconSrvc app = new NotifIconSrvc();
  app.enterEventDispatcher();
 }
}
```

Main application:

```
public class NotifIconApp extends UiApplication 
    implements GlobalEventListener {    
 private Bitmap mIcon = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("icon.png");
 private Bitmap mIconActive = 
        Bitmap.getBitmapResource("icon_active.png");
 private Scr mScreen = new Scr();

 public NotifIconApp() {
  addGlobalEventListener(this);
  pushScreen(mScreen);
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  NotifIconApp app = new NotifIconApp();
  app.enterEventDispatcher();
 }

 public void eventOccurred(long guid, int count, int size, 
        Object object0, Object object1) {
  if (0x5a9f7caa171ab7b8L == guid) {
                    Bitmap icon = getUpdateIconBitmap(mIcon, count, size);
   HomeScreen.updateIcon(icon);
   Bitmap rolloverIcon = 
                        getUpdateIconBitmap(mIconActive, count, size);
   HomeScreen.setRolloverIcon(rolloverIcon);
   mScreen.updateScreen(count, size);
  }
 }

 private Bitmap getUpdateIconBitmap(Bitmap bmp, int count, int size) {
  int width = bmp.getWidth();
  int height = bmp.getHeight();
  Bitmap iconBmp = new Bitmap(width, height);
  Graphics g = new Graphics(iconBmp);
  XYRect rect = new XYRect(0, 0, width, height);
  g.drawBitmap(rect, bmp, 0, 0);

  g.setFont(g.getFont().derive(Font.BOLD, 20, Ui.UNITS_px,
    Font.ANTIALIAS_STANDARD, Font.COLORED_OUTLINE_EFFECT));

  String text = Integer.toString(count);
  g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
  g.drawText(text, 0, 2);

  text = Integer.toString(size) + " Kb";
  g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
  g.drawText(text, 0, height - 22);
  return iconBmp;
 }
}

class Scr extends MainScreen {
 LabelField mMessages;
 String mLabelText = "message count: ";
 String mTitleText = "message counter";

 public Scr() {
  add(mMessages = new LabelField(mLabelText));
  setTitle(mTitleText);
 }

 void updateScreen(int count, int size) {
  StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(Integer.toString(count));
  sb.append("/");
  sb.append(Integer.toString(size));
  sb.append("Kb");
  String text = sb.toString();
  setTitle(mTitleText + "(" + text + ")");
  mMessages.setText(mLabelText + text);
 }

 protected void makeMenu(Menu menu, int instance) {
  super.makeMenu(menu, instance);
  menu.add(mMenuGoBG);
 }

 MenuItem mMenuGoBG = new MenuItem("go background", 0, 0) {
  public void run() {
   UiApplication.getUiApplication().requestBackground();
  }
 };
}
```