# BlackBerry - How to set icon for Application?

Tags: blackberry, icons

I need to set up an icon for my application which must change when the focus is on that particular application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See Project->Properties->BlackBerry Project Properties->Resources

To change icon dynamically see [Add a notification icon at the status bar in BlackBerry JDE 4.5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699369/add-a-notification-icon-at-the-status-bar-in-blackberry-jde-4-5-0)

Also may be useful [Icons and indicators](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/17965/Icons_and_indicators_2_0_514453_11.jsp)

Answer (score 1):

If you use Blackberry 5.0 in eclipse, open Blackberry_App_Descriptor.xml (which is in the root of the project), find here tag Resources (create it if it doesn't exist) and type here

```
<Icons>
   <Icon CanonicalFileName="res/iconWithoutFocus.png" IsFocus="false"/>
   <Icon CanonicalFileName="res/iconWithFocus.png" IsFocus="true"/>
</Icons>
```