# BlackBerry:Image to be displayed on application displayed in simulator

Tags: image, blackberry, icons

I have created a BB application which gets displayed in the "Downloads" menu in the simulator. I want to display image on the application icon. I have no 
idea about how to do this.

Can any body please give me some hint or provide a code using which I can display image on my application which is displayed in the BB simulator.

Comment: you want to display image as application icon or display image ON APPLICATION ICON? Just like iPhone notification icon..

Comment: i want to display image as application icon.And when i click on it my application should get loaded

Comment: If I search stack overflow for "+blackberry +icon" the top result is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1807600/blackberry-how-to-set-icon-for-application and the first answer there is what you need.  This is a duplicate question.

Comment: Thanks Michael Donohue :) And sorry for posting duplicate question :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can programmatically set the icon using the HomeScreen class:

```
HomeScreen.updateIcon(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("SomePng.png"));
HomeScreen.setRolloverIcon(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("SomeOtherPng.png"));
```

Comment: Thank You so much jonathan.i have tried the above code.Its working fine.I appreciate ur help dear.Thanks again