# How to set an icon for an application in Blackberry?

Tags: blackberry

I need to place an icon in an application on the Blackberry platform.

Comment: duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1807600/blackberry-how-to-set-icon-for-application

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse--

```
1) Right click on project in tree view
2) click on properties
3) Blackberry project properties
4) click on resources tab
5) click on add button below icon files and browse your icon file
```

JDE--

```
1) Right click on project in tree view
2) click on properties
3) click on resources tab
4) click on add button below icon files and browse your icon file
```

Good to place your icon file inside the project.